# Android Drawable Layer List item Color access

Tags: android, android-drawable

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <item android:id="@android:id/background">
>     <shape>
>         <solid
>                 android:color="#FF0000" />
>     </shape>
> </item>
>
> <item
>     android:id="@android:id/progress">
>     <clip>
>         <shape>
>             <solid
>                 android:color="#00FF00" />
>         </shape>
>     </clip>
> </item>
>
> </layer-list>
> ```

This Drawable I am applying on Seekbar.
I have to access this Drawable in Code and change its "background"/"progress" Color.

But really I don't have any idea that how can I access it in a Code.

Please help me to do this.

**EDIT**

```
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
ClipDrawable cd = (ClipDrawable) ld.getDrawable(1);
cd.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: This is what you looking for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For fragment: `getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<your_drawable>);`

For activity: `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<your_drawable>);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is to access the Drawable instance but how can I change the "Progress" Color?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can alter the actual background color of the drawable from code, but you could apply a colorFilter:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
                drawable.setColorFilter(cf)
```